# Element not visible - Protractor

Tags: angularjs

**Failed: element not visible**

Estou tentado acessar um item de menu, mas está retornando como não visível. Tentei de duas formas:

```
var formalizationLink = element(by.id('menu7'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", formalizationLink.getWebElement());
formalizationLink.click();
```

E também:

```
let formalizationLink = element(by.id("menu7"));

if (formalizationLink.isPresent()) {
  formalizationLink.click();
  browser.sleep(500);
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Os itens do menu acima deste estão funcionando normalmente, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Oi.
Também sou novo no protractor. Você só quer clicar no element com o ID 'menu7'?
Se for isso, pode fazer da forma mais simples:

```
element(by.id('menu7')).click().then(() =>{
      //Fazer alguma coisa depois do menu estiver aberto
});
```